# ReactJS server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I use "SSR News - React" (https://github.com/ilkeraltin/react-ssr-news) to make a ReactJS app working with SSR. I use webpack like the example and I got it online with Nginx (on port 80), but I have a problem with executing bundle.js of the build of the ReactJS app (it is working on my local environment). I got the following console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at Object. (bundle.js:1)

When I add `libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'` to 'output' in the config of webpack.server.js, then I get the following console error where I am stuck:

> bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at bundle.js:1

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add any new package on your local that is not installed on server?

Comment: I'd look into NodeJs versions on the different envs too. Module support is now native and wasn't in earlier version of Node